# Android.view.inflateexception binary xml file

Tags: java, android, xml

i am working with an app it works fine in ics and it is not working in jelly bean.please help me. i am getting error with edit text.where in edit text i have placed image on left side.when i try to excute that i am getting error that android.view.inflateexception binary xml file 24.

```
<RelativeLayout
     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
     xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" 
     android:layout_width="match_parent" 
     android:layout_height="match_parent" 
     android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" 
     android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin" 
     android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin" 
     android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" 
     tools:context=".MainActivity" 
     android:background="@drawable/hiltibg">
<Button 
    android:id="@+id/submit" 
    android:layout_width="500dp" 
    android:layout_height="60dp" 
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/ticketNum" 
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" 
    android:layout_marginBottom="64dp" 
    android:background="@drawable/roundbutton" 
    android:text="@string/conti" 
    android:textColor="#ffffff" 
    android:textSize="25dp" 
    android:textStyle="bold"/>
<EditText 
    android:id="@+id/pwd" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_above="@+id/info" 
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" 
    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/pwd" 
    android:ems="10" 
    android:hint="@string/password_hint" 
    android:inputType="phone|textPassword" 
    android:textStyle="italic"/>
<EditText 
    android:id="@+id/ticketNum" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_above="@+id/pwd" 
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" 
    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/uname" 
    android:editable="false" 
    android:ems="10" 
    android:focusable="false" 
    android:inputType="phone|textPassword" 
    android:textStyle="italic"/>
<TextView 
    android:id="@+id/info" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_above="@+id/submit" 
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/pwd" 
    android:layout_marginBottom="52dp" 
    android:layout_marginLeft="58dp" 
    android:text="@string/info" 
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: unable to start activity ComponentInfo {}:android.view.inflateException:Binary xml file line #25: Error inflating class android.Widget.EditText

Comment: did u try what @Onnarr say?
how did you inflate the edittext?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if the above layout works... Since positioning is wrong everywhere...

Wrong positioning:

```
android:layout_above="@+id/info"
```

It should be:

```
android:layout_above="@id/info"
```